# wcf data service binding combobox

Tags: wcf, silverlight, data-binding, service, combobox

I have an application with silvelight and wcf data services.
I want to populate comboBox with value of my column 'City'

Can someone give me the correct way to do this, because  my function failed with System.InvalidOperationException !

```
public void GetCities(System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox cmbCity)
    {

        DataServiceQuery<String> userQuery = (DataServiceQuery<String>)proxy.CreateQuery<String>("GetCity");
                    try
        {
            userQuery.BeginExecute(
             (result) =>
             {
                 var userlist = new DataServiceCollection<string>(userQuery.EndExecute(result));

                 cmbCity.ItemsSource = userlist.ToList(); 

             }, null);

                       }
        catch (DataServiceQueryException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

In my WCF Data Service, :

```
 [WebGet]
public IQueryable<String> GetCity()
{
   return Usager.GetCity();
}
```

in my edmx project, I have this:

```
public static IQueryable<String> GetCity()
    {
        try
        {
            DataBaseEntities scv = new DataBaseEntities();
            return (from user in scv.Usager
                   select user.City).Distinct();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which function failed? The one in Silverlight, WCF or your .edmx?